# Trigger Workflow Job with commands in Linux (Cloud-init)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, github-actions, workflow, cloud-init

im trying to deploy my github repository on my ec2 instance with a terraform and cloud-init file. For the Github part i use Github Actions. There i have already made a workflow file for nodejs and this runs correctly. Every time i create a new Instance with the terraform file and cloud.init, the workflow file should build again to create a _work folder, which is important for further processes. Now my question is, how can i trigger this workflow file build with Linux commands in yaml?

Cloud-init File:

```
#cloud-config
runcmd:
  - apt-get update && apt-get install -y expect
  - mkdir react
  - cd react
  - curl -o actions-runner-linux-x64-2.301.2.tar.gz -L https://github.com/actions/runner/releases/download/v2.300.2/actions-runner-linux-x64-2.301.1.tar.gz
  - tar xzf ./actions-runner-linux-x64-2.300.1.tar.gz
  - yes "" | ./config.sh --url https://github.com/yuuval/react-deploy-aws --token AVYXWHVAXX2TB4J63XBJCIDDYB6TA
  - sudo ./svc.sh install
  - sudo ./svc.sh start
  - yes "" | sudo apt install nginx
  - cd _work
  - cd react-deploy-aws
  - cd react-deploy-aws
  - cd /etc/nginx/sites-available
  - sudo rm default
  - 
    echo "server {listen 80 default_server;server_name _;location / {root
    /home/ubuntu/react/_work/react-deploy-aws/react-deploy-aws/build;try_files
    \$uri /index.html;}}" | sudo tee /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
  - sudo service nginx restart
  - sudo chmod +x /home
  - sudo chmod +x /home/ubuntu
  - sudo chmod +x /home/ubuntu/react
  - sudo chmod +x /home/ubuntu/react/_work
  - sudo chmod +x /home/ubuntu/react/_work/react-deploy-aws
  - sudo chmod +x /home/ubuntu/react/_work/react-deploy-aws/react-deploy-aws
  - sudo chmod +x /home/ubuntu/react/_work/react-deploy-aws/build
```

I found this Github Page, but i can't figure out how to do it:
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions

The code should be between after this commands:

```
  - yes "" | sudo apt install nginx
```

Comment: You're wanting to run the same cloud-init config again? Cloud-init doesn't really work that way. Also, just FYI, you don't need a #cloud-config for this scenario. If you want to just run a bash script, you can put #!/bin/bash at the top and cloud-init will run the script.

Comment: I want to run the Job from Github again. Which is placed in this directory: https://github.com/yuuval/react-deploy-aws/blob/master/.github/workflows/node.js.yml. If i want to get this _work folder in my ec2 instance, For this to happen i need to rebuild this workflow file. @falcojr

Comment: https://github.com/yuuval/react-deploy-aws/actions/runs/3958471405/workflow There you can see that at the right half of the screen, there is placed a button named "rerun all jobs" or something. I want to run this with code in cloud-init @falcojr